# Cyclejs and trigger events with values

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs, cyclejs

I m trying to learn cyclejs and reactive programming, and I can't get how to manage events with values.

For example,I need to create four functions that makes some maths operations such as :

- addition
- substraction
- divison
- multiplication

Here's the code that I have :

```
function main ({DOM}) {

  const secondNumber$ = DOM
    .select('.second-number')
    .events('change')
    .map(ev => ev.target.value)
    .startWith(0)

  const firstNumber$ = DOM
    .select('.first-number')
    .events('change')
    .map(ev => ev.target.value)
    .startWith(0)

  const addClick$ = DOM
    .select('.add')
    .events('click')
    .merge(firstNumber$)
    .merge(secondNumber$)
    .filter(value => console.log(value))
    .scan((nb1, nb2) => nb1 + nb2)


  return {
    DOM: addClick$.map(result =>
      div([
        input('.first-number',{type:'text'}),
        input('.second-number',{type:'text'}),
        button('.add', 'Add'),
        h2('Result is : ' + result)
      ])
    )
  };
}
```

It doesn't work at all and I can't figure out in my mind what I m doing wrong out there.

I m looking for a simple explanation how can I make this working ? I feel just like the merging streams of secondNumber$ and firstNumber$ are not correct and I can't find why..

Any idea ?

EDIT : I got that I shouldn't use the operator I was using, but use withLatestFrom.

The fact is that I m using xstream and so I have to map / flatten :

```
import {
    div,
    h1,
    input,
    button
} from '@cycle/dom';

/**
 * Counter
 * @param  {Object} sources Contains the inputs
 * @return {Object} The output sinks
 */
function counter(sources) {

    const input1$ = sources.DOM
        .select('.input1')
        .events('input')
        .map(ev => ev.target.value)
        .startWith(0);

    const input2$ = sources.DOM
        .select('.input2')
        .events('input')
        .map(ev => ev.target.value)
        .startWith(0);

    const add$ = sources.DOM
        .select('.add')
        .events('click');

    const resultAddition$ = add$
        .map(ev => input1$
            .map(value => input2$
                .map(value2 => Number(value) + Number(value2)))
            .flatten())
        .flatten()
        .startWith(0);

    return {
        DOM: resultAddition$.map(item => {
            console.log(item); // triggered each time an input is modified
            return div([
                h1(`Super new value  : ${item}`),
                input('.input1', {
                    attrs: {
                        type: 'text'
                    }
                }),
                input('.input2', {
                    attrs: {
                        type: 'text'
                    }
                }),
                button('.add', 'Ajouter')
            ]);
        })
    };
}

export default counter;
```

From now, I have got in mind what the code should do, mapping on each click the operation and flatten the two input$ to get my result *only when clicking the button*

The fact is that the result value is changing on input and not and click. And more important, *it changes on input **only after the first click** on the add button* that is not what I want to.

What am I doing wrong this time ?

Thanks for your replies

Comment: It's almost like the [BMI example](http://cycle.js.org/basic-examples.html) except you only calculate when the "Add" button is clicked.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you want `combineLatest`, not `merge`.
Both `combineLatest` and `merge` are "combination operators". They bring multiple Observables together and output one Observable. However, `combineLatest` is for "AND" combinations, while `merge` is for "OR" combinations.

You probably need "AND", because you want the value from first-number AND the value from second-number. That said, you want those values only when an add click happens. In that case, there is a variant of `combineLatest` called `withLatestFrom`. It allows you to sample the values from first-number AND second-number, but **only when** the add click happens.

```
const addClick$ = DOM
  .select('.add')
  .events('click')

const added$ = addClick$
  .withLatestFrom(firstNumber$, secondNumber$,
    (click, first, second) => first + second
  )
```

As a side note, you should never do something like `.filter(value => console.log(value))`. The function for filter is a *predicate*. It's supposed to be a "condition" function that returns a boolean. If you want to debug, use `.do(value => console.log(value))`.

PS: I'm assuming you were using RxJS v4.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. however I m using xstream and I have to map / flatten. I've editted my question based on your answer. Thank you for your job and your help